# Why is EJB Injection not working on Interceptor?

Tags: java, ejb, interceptor, java-ee-6

I created an interceptor that intercepts the call to my method and also its response. What happens is that I have to use a service while intercepting and the service works fine when intercepted on the request, but is null when intercepted on the response.

I tried separating the interceptor so the implementation of WriterInterceptor was in another class, but it seems to behavior the same.

```java
@POST
@Path("/test")
@MyAnnotation
public void test(
        final @Suspended AsyncResponse response,
        final @ApiParam(value = "Test.", required = true) @FormParam("test") String test)
        throws ServiceException {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(new AsyncResponseCallable(response) {

        @Override
        public Response execute() throws Exception {
            Object object = service.foo();
      Status status = Status.OK;

            return Response.status(status).entity(object).build();
        }
    });
}


@Provider
@MyAnnotation
public class MyInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @EJB
    private MyService myService;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object interceptor(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    myService.test();
        return context.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws WebApplicationException {
        myService.test();
    context.proceed();
    }

}

@Stateless
public class MyService {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

The method aroundWriteTo should have an instance of myService injected by the EJB annotation, but it is null.
Can you guys help me figure this out?

Comment: Try `@Inject` instead of `@EJB`.

Comment: @Thomas If I use ```@Inject```, the service doesn't load for both method calls.

Comment: So, I end up learning a little bit more about CDI and a colleague of mine pointed out that I had to have a beans.xml file for the ```@Inject``` to work. That solved my problem, although I still don't understand why wouldn't ```@EJB``` work.

Comment: Well, `@EJB` is the more specialized (and older) annotation which in many cases has been superseded by `@Inject` - e.g. in that CDI injection is supported in many more areas than injection in the "older" frameworks such as EJB, JPA etc. That being said, EJB injection didn't support injecting services into interceptors and since CDI is meant to be the superset of all those older disjunct frameworks that feature hasn't been "backported".